# When does geology tag should be used?

Tags: discussion

> The science comprising the study of the rocks Earth is composed of,
>   and the processes by which they change. Some subfields of geology are
>   petrology, mineralogy, and geophysics.

I don't know if geology tag should be included practically always or practically never when we are doing stratigraphy, structural-geology, tectonics....

Always I guess?

Answer (score 2):

Not always. Question related to oceanography, geography, climate and atmospheric sciences are often completely unrelated to geology.

You have to look to the most specific tags that represents a question. And quite often a tag as general as [geology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geology) will fall off the maximum limit of 5 tags.

For example a question about how subduction zone can create an antactic mountain range could be tagged with [geology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geology), but you should use first more specific tags like [plate-tectonics](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plate-tectonics), [subduction](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subduction), [antactica](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/antactica), [orogeny](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orogeny), [mountain-building](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mountain-building), and by this point can't add any more tags. Consequently, very general tags like [geology](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geology), are often used only in very general questions.